# Realurl rewrite without extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

I'm using a website running TYPO3 6.2 with Realurl extension.

In the tree I created a "Cars" page with ID #66 and with "cars/" as speaking url path segment. My page is now available with `https://www.mywebsite.com/cars/`. Cool.

What I need, if going on `https://www.mywebsite.com/cars/audi`, is to retrieve the `audi` as a GET variable (GP:car_brand) in Typoscript but current Typo3 default behavior is to search for a `audi` page below the existing `cars` page... and then display a 404 error.

What I have already tried:

1/ Adding a RewriteRule inside the .htaccess: `RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)$ /index.php?id=66&car_brand=/$1 [P]`. It works but the user is redirected to `https://www.mywebsite.com/cars/?car_brand=audi`, and we really need to keep the `cars/audi/` URL scheme which is more SEO compliant / user friendly.

2/ Adding custom configuration inside my realurl_conf.php postVarSets but realurl is very hard to understand and I don't have the technical skills to deal with it:

```
<?php

'postVarSets' => [
    66 => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'car_brand',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'no-comments' => 1
            ),
        

    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        )
    ),

    ...

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a userFunc, have a look there :

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#userfunc

In realurl_conf.php :

```
'postVarSets' => array(
    '66' => array(
        'brand' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'car_brand',
                'userFunc' => 'Vendor\Userfuncs\Example->myExampleFunction',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

In your class :

```
namespace Vendor\Userfuncs;
class Example {
    function myExampleFunction($params, $ref) {
        if ($params["decodeAlias"]) {
            return ($decodedAlias));
        } else {
            return ($encodedAlias));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have succeeded by replacing the page ID '66' by the URL slug I want in the realurl_conf.php. By the way, the conf has to be inside the '_DEFAULT' array of `postVarSets`

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this :

```
'postVarSets' => array(
    '66' => array(
        'brand' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'car_brand',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

So the URL will look like this

https://www.mywebsite.com/cars/brand/audi

May be there is also a solution with fixedPostVars to avoid the 'brand' segment but in that case, the get parameter '?car_brand=xxx' must be always set so I think it not possible to have only : https://www.mywebsite.com/cars

Or another solution could be to use a **userFunc**, then you can manage yourself the URL encoding/decoding.

Florian

Comment: It does not work... It would be more relevant to use the `userFunc` method. Di you have any documentation / examples / snippet about it ?